# How do I delete or remove temporary assets?

Tags: assets, filecache

Images were uploaded to a matrix field and then the changes were not saved, but the assets still show up in the control panel as selectable.

The asset seems to be stored here:

`http://example.com/admin/resources/tempassets/field_51/file_name.jpg`

I'd like to delete or remove these so that we dont't have them laying around taking up the desired file name. If I upload the same image again it appends a `_x` to the end of the file name as the number of times it's been uploaded.

I can't find the assets anywhere in the assets page in the control panel.

Comment: I was able to find the files uploaded to the root of my assets path and deleted them there, updated assets index / cleared cache and seems to be all solved. Will leave open for another hour or two to see if anyone else has an idea other than that.

Comment: Thanks Bill! Feel free to answer your own question, and even mark it correct if nothing better comes along!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From my comment above:**

I was able to find the files uploaded to the root of my assets path and deleted them there.

Then on the control panel settings page:

Updated Asset Indexes and Cleared Cache and it seems to be all working.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you should be able to right-click on the image from the main Asset index page in the control panel and select delete from there as well.

Comment: Hey Brad. I thought I had tried that originally and they were no where to be found. But you are right, it turns out that when I was going to the assets page, it was showing my asset source in an already expanded state. Had I clicked on the asset source name on the left I would have found them in it's root. Thanks! Didn't realize they could be stored there :x